# Receive Unix Timestamp and convert time to milliseconds WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, unix, timestamp

I receive a unix timestamp in my wp7 app and i want to convert it to milliseconds..

I make this:

```
time.Ticks / 10000;
```

Is this correct? this give the total time in milliseconds or only the milliseconds?

I want the total time in milliseconds..

my method to get the time is this:

```
void _ntpClient_TimeReceived(object sender, NtpClient.TimeReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        DateTime time = e.CurrentTime;

        long milliseconds = time.Ticks / 10000;
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `time`? If you've received a Unix timestamp, presumably you've got an integer in seconds since the unix epoch? It's not clear what input you've got and what you want the output to be.

Comment: if i convert the e.current time to a string i have something like this: 12/14/2011 10:48:46 PM

Comment: Unix time is usually seconds + nanoseconds, it is not clear what you have at all, thus impossible to answer how to convert it...

Comment: i use this example to get the ntp time: http://www.j2i.net/blogEngine/post/2011/08/07/Windows-Phone-NTP-Client.aspx  can you help me? i don't understand very well the code..

Comment: The example you reference does not indicate that this is a Unix time.  In fact, it returns a `DateTime`.  What makes you think this is a Unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix generally stores time as either seconds, or a `struct timespec` that contains both seconds and microseconds for further precision.  When referring to dates, it is the number of seconds (or seconds and microseconds) elapsed since January 1, 1970.

However, these are **never** referred to as "ticks".  "Ticks" generally refer to the Windows/.NET style time units - a "tick" is equal to 100 nanoseconds.  When referring to dates, it is the number of hundred nanosecond units that have elapsed since January 1, 0001.

If you have an object with "ticks", then yes, simply dividing by 10000 will convert the units to milliseconds.  Alternately, you can use a `TimeSpan`:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(ticks);
millis = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
```